# Heyzap only show a banner on a screen

Tags: android, facebook, admob, ads, heyzap

I try show 2 banner on 1 screen, but it only show 1 banner. Banner 1 loaded and show, but when banner 2 loaded, it is showed and banner 1 is empty. My code can't show both 2 banner. Can you help me.

My CODE:

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:initAds"})
public static void initAds(FrameLayout view, MainData data) {
    if (data.getAds() > 0) {
        AdsUtil.addBannerAds(view, data);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //AdsUtil.addBannerAds(view, data);
}

public static void addBannerAds(final FrameLayout bannerWrapper, final MainData data)
{
    Activity mActivity = IxuApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();
    BannerAdView bannerAdView = new BannerAdView(mActivity);
    HeyzapAds.setNetworkCallbackListener(new HeyzapAds.NetworkCallbackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNetworkCallback(String network, String event) {
            Log.e("tungtung",network + " " + event);
        }

    });
    HeyzapAds.BannerOptions bannerOptions = bannerAdView.getBannerOptions();
    bannerOptions.setFacebookBannerSize(HeyzapAds.CreativeSize.BANNER);
    bannerOptions.setAdmobBannerSize(HeyzapAds.CreativeSize.BANNER);
    bannerOptions.setGenericBannerSize(HeyzapAds.CreativeSize.BANNER);
    if(bannerWrapper.getChildCount()>0)
        bannerWrapper.removeAllViews();
    bannerWrapper.addView(bannerAdView);
    bannerAdView.setBannerListener(new HeyzapAds.BannerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdError(BannerAdView bannerAdView, HeyzapAds.BannerError bannerError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(BannerAdView bannerAdView) {
            if(data.getEnable()!=2)
                data.setShowLineForAds(1);
            bannerWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(BannerAdView bannerAdView) {

        }
    });
    bannerAdView.load();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say that if you are using our new 10.x unified SDK we no longer support multiple simultaneous banner placements.  It's a limitation of the new SDK and we will are currently looking into the best solution.

If you are using the 9.x SDK I can give you a few notes:

In order to help ad delivery reliability, we suggest you do not modify the `View` visibility of the `BannerAdView` on your own and leave the view as `VISIBLE` throughout the lifecycle of the banner.

The next note is that the following code is destroying any existing banners when you call `addBannerAds`.

```
if(bannerWrapper.getChildCount() > 0)
    bannerWrapper.removeAllViews();
```

If you remove this code from your implementation you should be able to add multiple banners to the `bannerWrapper` at once and hopefully see multiple banners.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed.

Comment: Non multiple banners is an issue for me on the 10.x SDK. Maybe I'll use 9.x. I have multiple tabs each with a banner on the bottom so not having multiple banners is a bit of a showstopper :( :(